# Hide test from Visual Studio Test Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, xunit.net

Using `Fact(Skip = "Manual Only")` is not entirely satisfactory because, if I click directly on the test to run it, it's still ignored.

I want it to not appear in Test Explorer but I can still run it by clicking on it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Nice [trick from Jimmy Bogard](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2013/06/20/run-tests-explicitly-in-xunit-net/) is to use the fact that `Skip` is writable and react to something in the environment:

```
public class RunnableInDebugOnlyAttribute : FactAttribute
{
    public RunnableInDebugOnlyAttribute()
    {
        if (!Debugger.IsAttached)
            Skip = "Only running in interactive mode.";
    }
}
```

(Aside from that, no xUnit does not have an `[Interactive]`; the closest thing is `[Trait("Interactive","True")] and use that to either use the trait grouping in test explorer to remove them.

Finally, a 'cheat' way is to use TestDriven.Net, which doesnt care if there is an attribute (along with lots of other facilities).